# Why does Canvas.drawVertices thrown a null pointer exception when not passing a Paint object?

Tags: android, android-canvas

According to the [Canvas.drawVertices Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawVertices(android.graphics.Canvas.VertexMode, int, float[], int, float[], int, int[], int, short[], int, int, android.graphics.Paint)) it is valid to pass `null` as Paint, if also the `texs` parameter is `null`.

> *paint*  Specifies the shader to use if the texs array is non-null

When calling the `drawVertices` method with a `null` for Paint, this will cause a Null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because internally it calls

```
nativeDrawVertices(mNativeCanvas, mode.nativeInt, vertexCount, verts,
                   vertOffset, texs, texOffset, colors, colorOffset,
                  indices, indexOffset, indexCount, paint.mNativePaint);
```

and `paint.mNativePaint` will cause a NullPointerException if paint is null. The doc forgot to tell you that paint can't be null here :)

Also painting vertices without paint does not seem to be logical since paint defines the line type etc. And the doc does not state `paint is optional`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My usecase was to use the `colors` array to define the color with which the triangles are filled. (got it working now)